# Pre-build event command line not working when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, visual-web-developer-2010

I have specified some xcopy-operations to run when building my solution. This works fine when I build my solution. But when I debug my solution by hitting F5 the pre-build stuff is not executed.

I am using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

Any ideas why ?

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

If I first clean the solution and then hit debug immediately after that, it seems to work